# Donwload file using ASP.net web forms and AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I'm working on a ASP.net web form project , and i need to call a function that download a file ( written in c# ) using AJAX

is this possible ? and if yes , how i can do it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is possible, you should be able to find the resources to show you how if you search for them.

Comment: See for example https://gist.github.com/rreimi/2da5ce314b5de3061f44

Comment: [This will help you](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1156485/How-to-Create-and-Download-File-with-Ajax-in-ASP-N)